# This data display in ajax how to make align

Tags: php, ajax

[{"id":"19","name":"Bajaj Avenger","topspeed":"N/A","engine":"220 cc engine","weight":"154.5 kg (341 lb) (dry)","colors":"Black, Red, Blue and Silver","electricalsystem":"N/A","clutch":"N/A","fuelconsumption":"N/A","wheeltype":"Spokes","maximumpower":"19.03 Ps @ 8400 rpm (vs. 17.5 Ps @ 8000 rpm of older 200 cc engine)","maximumtorque":"17.5 Nm @ 7000 rpm (vs. 16.78 @ 6000 rpm of older 200 cc engine)","description":"The overall optimized length, height and width of the bike is 2195 mm, 1070 mm and 750 mm respectively with a wheel base of 1475 mm while the weight is merely 154 kg (without wind shield).\r\nThe ground clearance of Bajaj Avenger 220 is 169 mm equipped which is best among the cruiser with 15 inch wide tyres, multi spoke, and chrome plated wheels. The tyre specifications are 90/90-17 and 130/90-15 for front and rear ones respectively. The longest wheelbase of 1475 mm along with the stocky box-section swing-arm guarantees that Bajaj Avenger 220 can seize all the bumps without disconcerting its balance.","imagename":"300px-Bajaj_Avenger_220_DTS-i.jpg","Product_id":"1","Category_id":"3","Brands_id":"2","Engine_CC_Models_id":"37","Prise_id":"5","Body_Style_id":"4","ByFuelType_id":"2","Mileage_id":"3","IndianPrise":"77,860","BrandNames":"5"}]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `jQuery`, All you need is this where `data` is your json object.Write down below function into `success handler`

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    alert(data[i].name);
});​



$.ajax({ 
type : 'POST',
url: 'localhost/TEMP/Compare/Display_Brand_Models',
data : data, colModel : [ { id : 'User ID', name : 'id' }],
  success : function(data){ 

       $.each(data, function(i, item) {
         alert(data[i].name);
         //here you write whatever you want.
         $('#Display_ComPare').html('<div>'+data[i].name+'</div>');} 
       });​


  }
);
```

Comment: $.ajax({
     type : 'POST',
     url: 'http://localhost/TEMP/Compare/Display_Brand_Models',
     data : data,
      colModel : [ {
        id : 'User ID', name : 'id'
      }],
     success : function(data){
      
      $('#Display_ComPare').html('<div>'+data.name+'</div>');}  
        });